# Verifying the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that

$z(x,w) = e^{-\pi w/2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x }{2}\right) + 2e^{-5\pi w/2}\cos\left(\frac{5\pi x}{2}\right)$

satisfies the differential equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial w^2} =0\hspace{.5in} $$
in $\left\{(x,w): -1<x<1,\ w>0\right\}$

and boundary conditions 
$$z(x,0) =  \cos\left(\frac{\pi x }{2}\right) + 2\cos\left(\frac{5\pi x}{2}\right)$$ 
and 
$$z(1,w) = z(-1,w) = 0.$$

Comment: And your effort?

Comment: $$f(x,w) = e^{-\pi w/2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x }{2}\right) + 2e^{-5\pi w/2}\cos\left(\frac{5\pi x}{2}\right)={\bf Re}\,\left(e^{\frac12\pi z}+e^{\frac52\pi z}\right)$$
is the real part of analytic function $e^{\frac12\pi z}+e^{\frac52\pi z}$ so it is harmonic on
$$\{z=-w+ix\,:\,-1<x<1,\ w>0\}$$

Comment: You just need to do the differentiations.